# Installed 2 Versions of Anaconda - libraries don't work

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, path, anaconda

I have mistakenly installed 2 versions of Anaconda on my 2019 Mac Pro and now I cannot access python libraries.

In an attempt to update anaconda I installed another version using homebrew instead of the GUI installer and it seems to have changed the path to my libraries. Now when I try to run a python script in the terminal I get a module not found error.

Even with the most basic libraries such as numpy and pandas:

```
    import numpy as np 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Though they still show up when I run a `pip list`...

Can anybody recommend how to fix this? I set up this machine a long time ago and woud still consider myself a low intermediate user. I use zshell in the terminal and originally set the path to anaconda in .zshrc as below.

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/canderson/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/canderson/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/canderson/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/canderson/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
```

As a test, when I try and install numpy with pip it returns requirement already satisfied. Even though It's returning module not found.

```
pip3 install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.20.0)
```

** EDIT **

I've noticed this is only an issue with VS Code. When I run the same code in a standalone terminal it works fine.

Comment: What is the output of `which python`? And `which pip3`?

Comment: ```/usr/bin/python3```

Comment: ```/usr/local/bin/pip3```

Comment: That's the problem. It is two different locations

Answer (score 0):

When there are multiple versions of python on the machine, you should choose the correct interpreter for vscode. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette and search for and select `Python:Select Interpreter`. Select a correct interpreter in the **Select Interpreter** panel.

[image]

If you can run the same code correctly in a standalone terminal, you can use the following code to print out the current interpreter.

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

[image]

Then set it as the default interpreter in the ***settings.json*** and select this interpreter in the **Select Interpreter** panel, then the code in vscode should also be able to run correctly.

```json
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "E:\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe",
```

[image]